# chrome extension popup.js is not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup.html that looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/fbh-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fbh-popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width: 200px">
    <div id="fbh-main">
        <div id="fbh-popup-enabled"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And fbh-popup.js looks like this

```
$('#fbh-popup-enabled').html('test');
```

The JS should alter the content of the div but does not. I even tried a simple console.log('test') in the JS file and that didn't fire. I am at a loss.

Comment: I think your scripts should be added as content scripts. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: One of the samples at Google showed popup.html calling popup.js in the head tag.

Comment: Just asking... your `$('#fbh-popup-enabled').html('test');` is inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write your code inside [ready event callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fbh-popup-enabled').html('test');
});
```