# Popup.js not working for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Currently I am working on a chrome extension and with the popup.html I cannot get the popup.js to work

`popup.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body style="width: 15rem; height: 15rem">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 10px"> 
        <input id="url" />
        <button type="button" id="newDetails">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script src="./popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`

```js
console.log("Hello")
let btn = document.getElementById("newDetails");
btn.onclick = function () {
  console.log("Clicked!");
};
```

I have already looked at plenty of questions/answers (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382365/js-function-not-defined-chrome-extension-popup-js),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785101/chrome-extension-popup-js-is-not-working),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396977/getelementbyid-not-working-in-popup-js-chrome-extension)) but none have been able to fix my issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so, the popup shows, but the js isn't loading?

Comment: Yes, I see the popup but when I click the button it does not print the desired function. In addition, I have just included a `document.addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded, function(){}` but still nothing

Comment: Have you tried `alert` instead of `console.log`? The `console.log` only logs in the popup's console, not the current page's.

Comment: not even `Hello` is on the console?

Comment: The alert works! Is there any way for me to check the popup's console?

Comment: You need to go to `chrome://extensions/`, and click the `Inspect views background page` on your extension to see the popup's console. Also in dev tools, you can pick the source by choosing the extension on the dropdown that says `top` by default(but that's probably only for `background.js`)

Comment: Sorry, that's also for the background script. Here's the way how you should do it: [Cannot get Chrome popup.js to use console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858909/cannot-get-chrome-popup-js-to-use-console-log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved! Answered by Hao Wu in the comments of the original post.

Needed to check the popup's console vs the browser console. You can do that by right clicking the extension and inspecting it.